# Выбор CMS для портала под приложения для мобильных систем

Tags: cms

Люди добрые, помогите определиться с выбором CMS для создания портала под приложения для мобильных систем с возможностью ведения блогов, элементами социальной сети (кабинет, друзья, переписка, клубы), новостями и возможностью покупать / продавать эти приложения или устройства.  CMS должна спокойно выдерживать нагрузка 10000 уников в сутки, одновременно 500-2000 уников. Drupal, InstantCMS уже рассматривались, но были исключены из-за своей неповоротливости и прожорливости (ИМХО). Может быть кто-то сталкивался с аналогичным проектом и нашёл золотую середину? Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[liveStreet CMS](http://livestreet.ru/) не смотрели? Хабр же выдерживает.

Comment: Дело не только в wvc? дело в серверах и их настройках.

Сама cms может быть написана на коленке :)

Comment: Тут уже смотря что проще, готовую (и неплохую кстати) CMS допилить, или "на коленке" склепать CMS под хайлоад.
А так да, согласен любые хайлоад проекты требуют тонкой настройки окружения под сам проект.

Answer (score 0):

Ищещь инвесторов.

Создаешь сайт с нуля у хорошей компании, и вот тебе твоя CMS в которой будет то что тебе нужно.

Любую бесплатную CMS придется вертеть и настраивать под себя.

Answer (score 0):

[SLAED CMS](http://www.slaed.net/index.php?name=shop&op=view&id=22)